# How can I implement - when text selection is gone, the coloured text by selection is coming back to colour before selection (in swift, cocoa)?

Tags: swift, cocoa, notifications

I have text in two textviews and when I select some part of text in one textview window, I can change color of text of the same text in second textview , if second textview has it. Then, when this selection is gone, the colored text in second textview is still there. I have used to get such functionality the notification NSTextViewDidChangeSelectionNotification. Question is how can I implement the situation when the previous selection is gone the colored text is coming back to previous color ? It will be easy to do if there is some kind of notification saying that text is not selected anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is perform an action based on the length of your selection (you can obviously replace the `print` function with your own code):

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.selectedRange.length == 0 {
        print("No selection.")
    }
}
```

Note the `textViewDidChangeSelection` function will still fire when the insertion point changes (i.e. if you touch anywhere different in the textArea without making a selection), not just when the selection changes.

Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/selectedRange) out for more info from the documentation about the `selectedRange` range property of `textView`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! My mistake was direct usage of NSRange variable from selectedRange. It is always changing even if I didn't select a range (simple mouse klick gives range zero) and function to reverse back colour had always zero range. I have changed variable for used ranges.